# sql completion of a result where it miss some results in the sequence

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with sales information

like this:    `|product | sales | date|`

Most of the time the date are consecutive from 201601 to 201652.
but some times there is a gap ex : no line for 201602 for productA

How can I make an SQL query that will return a result for this gap like this :

```
productA,4,201601

**productA,0,201602**

productA,5,201603

productA,8,201604

(...)
```

instead of :

```
productA,4,201601

productA,5,201603

productA,8,201604

(...)
```

Of course it will also be some product B,C,...

Comment: the version is oracle 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this by using `cross join` to get all the rows and then `left join` to pull in the values.

Assuming you have *some* data for each week:

```
select p.product, d.date, coalesce(s.sales, 0) as sales
from (select distinct product from sales) p cross join
     (select distinct date from sales) d left join
     sales s
     on s.product = p.product and s.date = d.date;
```

If you have tables of products and dates, you can use those instead of the subqueries.

Comment: what if all combination of date not present in sales table?

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara - Make a calendar table and join against that.

Comment: @MatBailie we can use data dictionary table as well. see my below response.

Comment: @Adf . . . You should try it before saying it will be really costly.

Comment: Actualy I am curently, thanks for all your answer by the way. What is the rule to chose what reponse I validate ?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from oracle 10g you can use `partition outer join` to produce desired result:

```
   -- sample of data
   with sales(product, sales, dt) as(
      select 'product A', 4, 201601 from dual union all
      select 'product A', 5, 201603 from dual union all
      select 'product A', 8, 201604 from dual
    ),
    -- here we generate months for the year 2016
    mnth(dt) as(
      select 201600 + level
        from dual
      connect by level <= 12
    )
    -- actual query
    select s.product
        , nvl(s.sales, 0) as sales
        , m.dt as date1 
      from sales s
          partition by(s.product)
          right join mnth m
                 on (m.dt = s.dt)
     order by s.product, m.dt
```

Result:

```
PRODUCT        SALES      DATE1
--------- ---------- ----------
product A          4     201601
product A          0     201602
product A          5     201603
product A          8     201604
product A          0     201605
product A          0     201606
product A          0     201607
product A          0     201608
product A          0     201609
product A          0     201610
product A          0     201611
product A          0     201612

 12 rows selected
```

Comment: Partition outer join *rocks*! \o/

Answer (score 0):

based on Gordon's response, I edited so date does not depend on Sales table. Here assumption is that tab will have atleast 52 row, if not please use appropriate data-dictionary table from oracle.

```
select p.product, d.date, coalesce(s.sales, 0) as sales
from (select distinct product from sales) p cross join
     (select 2016 || rownum rn from tab where rownum<=52) d left join
     sales s
     on s.product = p.product and s.date = d.date;
```